# What are the differences between the Adults Only and Mature versions of Manhunt 2?

Tags: manhunt-2

I was looking at the old releases by Rockstar Games, and I found out that [Manhunt 2 has two different ESRB ratings](https://www.esrb.org/search/?searchKeyword=Manhunt+2):

- Adults Only on PC

[image]

- Mature on the PS2, PSP and Wii

[image]

What are the differences between this two sets of versions/releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhunt_2) on the game,

> Originally scheduled for North American and European release in July, the game was suspended by Rockstar's parent company Take-Two Interactive when it was refused classification in the United Kingdom and Ireland, and given an Adults Only (AO) rating in the United States.[[1]](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/manhunt-2-pc-gets-ao-rating/1100-6216220/) As Nintendo, Microsoft, and Sony Computer Entertainment do not allow AO titles on their systems, this effectively (if not technically) would have banned the game in the US as well.[[2]](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/sony-nintendo-forbid-ao-rated-manhunt-2/1100-6172830/) In response to these ratings problems, Rockstar censored the game, blurring the screen during the game's executions and removing the scoring system, where players were awarded for particularly brutal killings.[[3]](http://www.mtv.com/news/1572934/manhunt-2-developer-finally-talks-about-game-ratings-controversy-much-as-it-pains-him/) This edited version was rated M in the US by the ESRB and was released on 29 October.